# Intuitive blinds roll up/roll down mechanism

Tags: windows

By all means a "champagne problem", but half of the time I try to operate roll-up blinds, I get the blinds moving in the wrong direction. The cord is completely outside of the blinds, and it can easily twist, so I can't tell which of the two sides at the bight of the cord to pull.

[image: Which part of the cord do I pull?!]

What mechanisms for opening and closing blinds eliminate this guesswork?

Comment: A glance at the winding direction of the blind roll should give you an easy clue, no? Normally the blind fabric comes off the window side, so down on the outer run is down on the blind. Just picture how it works.

Comment: your question has nothing to do with home improvement ... ask someone to slap you everytime you roll the blinds the wrong way ... lol ....  `It's just statistics after all` means that you are not paying attention to what you are doing

Comment: @isherwood: if the cord is half behind and half in front of the blinds, yes. I've clarified the question and added a photo of my actual case, where this doesn't happen.

Comment: Yeah, those suck. IDK what to tell you.... Mark the handle thing on one side so that eventually you'll know which string to pull if you're looking at the mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm happy with this solution, which separates the up and down runs.

[image: Distinct sides for blinds cord]

Comment: Glad you found a solution and thanks for coming back to post your answer!

Comment: @FreeMan: I think it's the same as [LarryBud's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/182049/intuitive-blinds-roll-up-roll-down-mechanism/182063#182063), just with a photo?

Answer (score 1):

If this is all you have to worry about in your house, consider yourself lucky. 
Have you considered putting a motorized drive on this blind? There are a few on the market that operate from your phone or manually. I am not endorsing any products but did come across the one shown below. Good luck.

[image]

https://www.blindstogo.com/en/shop/move

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I ever did was mount the bottom plastic piece to the wall/window sill so it's not flipping and flopping all over the place and changing orientation, and make sure that any blinds I have has the "open" on one side, and the "close" on the other, making them consistent throughout the house.

Beyond that, you could always put a piece of tape on the "open" side.